# context.awsRequestId from lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless-framework

Is the uuid from `context.awsRequestId` really unique? I want to use it in association with the creation of a resource, so I can now when the resource was created:

```
const uuid = require('uuid');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.create = (event, context, callback) => {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  if (typeof data.text !== 'string') {
    console.error('Validation Failed');
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 400,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
      body: 'Couldn\'t create the todo item.',
    });
    return;
  }

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
    Item: {
      id: context.awsRequestId,
      text: data.text,
      checked: false,
      createdAt: timestamp,
      updatedAt: timestamp,
    },
  };

  // write the todo to the database
  dynamoDb.put(params, (error) => {
    // handle potential errors
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: error.statusCode || 501,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
        body: 'Couldn\'t create the todo item.',
      });
      return;
    }

    // create a response
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(params.Item),
    };
    callback(null, response);
  });
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this is clearly documented, but based on observations, these UUIDs do not appear to be randomly generated (which is good for uniqueness).  Instead, they look like they are a variant of [Type 1 UUIDs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), where most of the bytes actually represent a timestamp, so it would appear to be a safe assumption that they are both spatially and temporally unique.

When the digit `M` in `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Mxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` is set to 1, the UUID should be a Type 1 and should represent a high resolution timestamp and "node" identifier, although in this case the node component seems to carry no meaningful information... but the timestamps seem close to real time (though not precisely so).

Comment: I a environment where the same lambda is run concurrent many times we might get the same id if it is really timestamp based and the node identifier carries no meaning. I'm still trying to figure out how to get a unique id for the current "lambda instance"

Comment: @jWang1 the most likely definition for "lambda instance" is "container."  Is that what you're referring to?  Or do you mean invocation?

Comment: Ah yes I mean container.